# Application Fails to start with Springboot RC2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Upgrading from spring boot RC1 to spring boot RC2 is breaking builds on multiple projects. I decided to post here before raising an issue. We looked through release notes and don't see any changes we needed to make other than actuator configuration.

Looking at this commit it appears maybe a new Milestone release of Spring cloud streams is needed https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/commit/43ea0461ee16e1ee6f250ece8c82f323f2aef2ae

Using These Versions

```
kotlinVersion=1.2.21
springBootVersion=2.0.0.RC2
springCloudVersion=Finchley.M6
springCloudStreamsVersion=Elmhurst.M4
```

we are getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BINDER_BEAN_NAME
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:238) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:709) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:136) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:351) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at datahub.supplychain.SupplyChainSvcApplication$Companion.main(SupplyChainSvcApplication.kt:13) [classes/:na]
    at datahub.supplychain.SupplyChainSvcApplication.main(SupplyChainSvcApplication.kt) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BINDER_BEAN_NAME
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BINDER_BEAN_NAME
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.configurationPropertiesBeans(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$102b6094.CGLIB$configurationPropertiesBeans$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$102b6094$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3a233345.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$102b6094.configurationPropertiesBeans(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**

On 2nd of March, 2018 Spring Cloud Finchley M8 is released.   https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/02/spring-cloud-finchley-m8-is-available

From [release notes](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/02/spring-cloud-finchley-m8-is-available#notable-changes-in-the-finchley-release-train):

> Finchley.M8 is compatible with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Finchley.M8 is the solution for springboot2.0.0.rc2 and for springboot2.0.0.RELEASE also

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

**OLD SOLUTION**

If you use the latest version for spring cloud (Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) it will fix the issue.

Probably they will release a new version soon.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2 is not compatible with Spring Cloud Finchley.M6. You have to use Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 or wait until there is a newer Spring Cloud version available.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use parent with version `2.0.0.RC1` and cloud `Finchley.M6` and these dependencies. [I created my pom.xml according to this sample and everything seems to work properly](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-gateway-sample/blob/master/pom.xml) I also needed to remove `log.level` from *.yml configuration, because of missing map converter.

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
    <relativePath/> 
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M6</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you see the issue. The latest milestones with the upgrade to Spring Boot RC2 are not out given that RC2 literally just got released.

I'd encourage you to hold off upgrading to new boot versions if you have integrated in Spring Cloud. You wouldn't update to new version of Spring Framework without Spring Boot having released their dependent version.

Comment: I get what you are saying but yes I also expect that an release candidate bump would not break projects that are closely related.  I expect incremental stability towards GA.

Comment: A spring boot RC is not a Spring Cloud RC nor do they release at the same time. Im not sure what you expect in this regards when you upgrade hours after a release while knowing Spring cloud is built against Spring Boot.